# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 12559948 byte allocation with 2232360 free bytes and 2MB until OOM

Tags: java, android, image

Actually, I am trying to create a app with  multimedia files which includes images . While I am loading the app in any devices facing the problem, the apps get crash in the middle of the process with the error "

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 12559948 byte
>   allocation with 2232360 free bytes and 2MB until OOM"

.

I also declare in my manifest these code:

```
<application
    android:name=".AppHelper.AppController"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ring_logo"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:largeHeap="true"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14596970/give-more-memory-to-my-jar-file

Comment: increse the heap size this may help <link>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452765/how-to-increase-heap-size-of-jvm</link>

Comment: The error explains itself

Comment: @Tinki not actually, this error is getting from android when trying to load big image

Comment: why i getting negative vote ??????????is any wrong question asking by me ??????please suggest me..

Answer (score 0):

Its usually due placing  high resolution images in wrong `drawable` folder.
For Example, you have an image whose resolution and density is high (Suppose 640dpi) and  you place it inside `drawble` folder instead of `drawable-xxxhdpi` folder. When app will run on high resolution device, System will try to scale up that image according to resolution of the device. Resulting image will take more memory and `OutOfMemory` exception will be thrown after sometime of using app. So you should create images for every possible density (dpi,hdpi,xdpi,xxdpi,xxxdpi) or put your high resolution image inside drawable-xxxhdpi. System will scale down automatically for lower densities.